# remove extra characters from a string line in c

Tags: c, string, getchar

I had an assignment to write a program that takes 2 arguments as string by `getchar` and saves in variables. The 2nd string defines the length of the 1st string, which means that if the first string has 23 characters and the 2nd one has 13, the code will print the **13 first characters of the 1st string** and will **remove the rest**. the question contained a code and I had to complete the missing parts. I wrote my code but my program gives me the output in a loop and without the `for` loop it doesn't work properly.

I couldn't understand why didn't it work so I would be very thankful and happy if anyone could help me.

**input:**

string 1: `this is a sample string` (23 chars)

string 2: `sample length` (13 chars)

**output**:

`this is a sam` (13 chars)

**the original code was this:**

```
/*Gets one line of data from standard input. Returns an empty string on
  end of file. If data line will not fit in allotted space, stores
  portion that does fit and discards rest of input line.*/

char *
scanline(char *dest,    /* output   - destination string        */
         int  dest_len) /* input    - space available in dest   */
{
      int i, ch;
      /* Gets next line one character at a time.                */
      i = 0;
      for (ch = getchar();
           ch != '\n' && ch != EOF && i < dest_len - 1;
           ch = getchar())
          dest[i++] = ch;
     dest[i] = '\0';

    /* Discards any characters that remain on input line        */
    while (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF)
        ch = getchar();

    return (dest);
}
```

**The following code is mine which has problem with the output and might have other bugs but it was my best try:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BuffSize 256

char *scanline(char *dest, int dest_len)/* output - destination string */ /* input - space available in dest */
{
int i, ch;
char temp[BuffSize];

//get the first string and store in temp
i = 0;
for (ch = getchar(); ch != '\n' && ch != EOF && i < BuffSize; ch = getchar())
{temp[i++] = ch;
temp[i] = '\0';}
int len= strlen(temp);

printf("enter second string\n");
/* Gets next line one character at a time. */
i = 0;
int cha;
for (cha = getchar(); cha != '\n' && cha != EOF && i < dest_len - 1; cha = getchar())
{dest[i++] = cha;
dest[i] = '\0';}
dest_len= strlen(dest);
strncpy(dest, temp, dest_len);
dest[dest_len]='\0';

/* Discards any characters that remain on input line */
while (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF)
ch = getchar();
return (dest);
}

int main()
{
    char dest[BuffSize];
    char temp[BuffSize];
    int dest_len;
    printf("enter string\n");
    scanline(dest, dest_len);
    
    //my code has problem without the following loop
    for (int i=0; i<=dest_len; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", dest);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One thing I notice is that `dest_len` is never initialized in `main`.  You never use it in your `scanline` function, so it doesn't end up mattering, but does mean you don't protect against writing more characters than `dest` can hold.  But back in `main` you loop from 0 to `dest_len`, which is uninitialized.

Comment: How can i initialize it when I have to find the `dest_len` in `scanline` function? i mean the process of scanning is in that function and after that, I can find `dest_len` so how should I refer it in my loop? @OutrageousBacon

Comment: You should do yourself a favor and format your code properly. It's hard to work with poorly formatted code even for us let alone for you.

Comment: Ok well, in the original `scanline` function you posted, `dest_len` acted as a limit to prevent more than that number of characters being read into `dest`, i.e. it prevented overflow.  If you want YOUR `dest_len` to be an output containing the actual length of string written into `dest`, then you need to declare it as `int*` so that the value is returned to the caller (i.e. it is an output parameter).  But it still doesn't solve the problem that you aren't limiting the writing into `dest` in any way and are still subject to overflow.

Comment: I see. I'll work on it, thank you for the information and help. @OutrageousBacon

Comment: Also note that doing `printf` in a loop in `main` doesn't make sense.  `printf("%s", dest);` already prints the whole string contained in `dest` (assuming it is null-terminated properly) so there's no need for a loop at all just a single print statement.

Comment: yes it is hard. I have to work on it as well. thanks for reminding me. @Jabberwocky

Comment: that was the problem. at first i thought it will work without loop but after deleting `for` it didn't work at all @OutrageousBacon

Comment: This is actually fairly hard to do in ISO C without some limits as to the size of the string; I certainly wouldn't give it out to beginners. Maybe ask what reasonable sizes that you can be sure that you're not going to exceed are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem in code was this part

```
    for (int i=0; i<=dest_len; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", dest);
    }
```

so basically I changed `dest_len` with `sizeof(dest)` as `sizeof()` returns the size required here by the pointer type, so the code worked properly without referring to `dest_len` which was not initialized. This is the final code that didn't have bug and gave the correct output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BuffSize 256

char *scanline(char *dest, int dest_len)/* output - destination string */ /* input - space available in dest */
{
int i, ch;
char temp[BuffSize];

//get the first string and store in temp
i = 0;
for (ch = getchar(); ch != '\n' && ch != EOF && i < BuffSize; ch = getchar())
{temp[i++] = ch;
temp[i] = '\0';}
int len= strlen(temp);

printf("enter second string\n");
/* Gets next line one character at a time. */
i = 0;
int cha;
for (cha = getchar(); cha != '\n' && cha != EOF && i < dest_len - 1; cha = getchar())
{dest[i++] = cha;
dest[i] = '\0';}
dest_len= strlen(dest);
strncpy(dest, temp, dest_len);
dest[dest_len]='\0';

/* Discards any characters that remain on input line */
while (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF)
ch = getchar();
return (dest);
}


int main()
{
    char dest[BuffSize];
    printf("enter string\n");
    printf("%s", scanline(dest, sizeof(dest)));
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

enter string

this is a sample line

enter second string

sample length

this is a sam

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 11.890 s